# How to attach a [formControl] to an type when instantiating it in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-aot, angular-compiler, angular-jit

I am trying to attach a `[formControl]` (and other top level attributes) to an object that I create with a `ComponentFactoryResolver` in order to handle the form logic with a `ControlValueAccessor`.

Basically I do this:

```
@Component({selector: 'my-selector', ... })
class ATypeWhichSupportsValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
    @Input()
    otherValuableAttribute: boolean = false;

    // Implementation of ControlValueAccessor
    // ...
    //
}

@Component({selector: 'my-dynamic', template: '<ng-template #container></ng-template>', ... })
class CreateDynamic {
    constructor(
        private vcRef: ViewContainerRef,
        private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
    ) {}

    @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef })
    container: ViewContainerRef;

    // ...

    create() {
        let type = ATypeWhichSupportsValueAccessor;
        let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(type);
        let injector = Injector.create([], this.vcRef.parentInjector);

        // How to attach top level attributes to my control here?
        this._factoryComponent = this.container.createComponent(factory, 0, injector);
    }
}
```

The only way I figured this out is by going in JIT and using a RuntimeCompiler, creating a template on the fly like `<my-component [formControl]="args" [otherValuableAttribute]="true"></my-component>`. Compiling this, then getting the instance.

However, I can't run this without turning off AOT.

What is my best option here?

Comment: Have you tried `this._factoryComponent.instance.formControl = ...`?

Comment: @yurzui You can't do that... there is plenty of Angular logic attached to the [formControl] that need to execute when the component is loaded in a template.

Comment: I thought your directive takes formControl input. There is no simple way to do this. Check similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181152/how-to-dynamically-add-ng-value-accessor-component-to-reactive-form

Comment: @yurzui yeah that's not the best solution, having to learn how the internal of formControl works.