# angular pass data to component created & compiled on the fly

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-compiler

A basic input component is created on the fly

```
const compTag = 'my-input';
const template = `<${compTag}></${compTag}>`;
```

`my-input` is an input which implements the `ControlValueAccessor` and can be assigned with a `formControlName` directive.

therefore, passing it a `formControlName=${config.name}`:

```
const template = `<${compTag} formControlName="${config.name}"></${compTag}>`;
```

in my on-the-fly component, the following is passed so that the control will find his parent:

```
viewProviders: [{
  provide: ControlContainer,
  useExisting: FormGroupDirectiv
}],
```

Verbose:

```
const tmpCmp = Component({
  template,
  viewProviders: [{
    provide: ControlContainer,
    useExisting: FormGroupDirective
  }],
})(class {});
```

which is later resolved in DOM as:

```
<ng-component>
  <my-input formcontrolname="a" ng-reflect-name="a" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <input/>
  </my-input>
</ng-component>
```

The problem is when I attempt to pass any Object config data to the child component in the template:

`` const template = `<${compTag} formControlName="${config.name}" config=${config}></${compTag}>`; ``

the `config` does pass on to the component, but not parsed properly, and received as `config: [Object object]`

has anyone stumbled upon?

Answer (score 0):

so [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181152/how-to-dynamically-add-ng-value-accessor-component-to-reactive-form) was extremely helpful.

This way the wrapper component was excused and the formControlName was directly attached to the created component.

extended answer:

what `formControlName` does per declaration from above (e.g `<my-input formControlName="myControl"></my-input>`

so does the `NgControl` class from below, extending the  `AbstractControlDirective` class.

it accepts the parameter 'name' which is the `Name` in `formControlName`
and by extending this class via a `Directive`, you can assign the component itself to the `valueAccessor` function from within.

the connection is made here (brought from the linked post):

```
const component = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<any>(components[this.config.type]);
this.name = this.config.name; // formControlName="..."
this.component = this.container.createComponent(component);
this.component.instance.config = this.config;
this.valueAccessor = this.component.instance; // The part where NgControl is connected via ControlValueAccessor to your component.
this._control = this.formDirective.addControl(this); // The part where the control knows which is its parent in the `ReactiveForm`
```