# appending to directives[] of FormGroupDirective

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-directives, angular-dynamic-components

currently the `FormGroupDirective.directives` reveals only `NgControl` directive extensions,
implemented following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181152/how-to-dynamically-add-ng-value-accessor-component-to-reactive-form?answertab=votes#tab-top) SOF answer of how to attach a `FormControlName` to a dynamically created component.

```
export class DynamicPanelDirective extends NgControl implements OnInit  {

  _control: FormControl;

  constructor(
    @Optional() @Host() @SkipSelf() private parent: ControlContainer,
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private container: ViewContainerRef) {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let component = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<GeneralPanelComponent>(GeneralPanelComponent);
    this.name = 'general';
    this.component = this.container.createComponent(component);
    this.valueAccessor = this.component.instance;
    this._control = this.formDirective.addControl(this);
  }
  ...
}
```

When logging `this.parent.formDirective.directives`, I get an array of all `DynamicPanelDirective`s attached to the `FormGroupDirective`

```
directives: Array(2)
0: DynamicPanelDirective {_parent: null, name: "input", valueAccessor: InputComponent, _rawValidators: Array(0), _rawAsyncValidators: Array(0), …}
1: DynamicPanelDirective {_parent: null, name: "select", valueAccessor: SelectComponent, _rawValidators: Array(0), _rawAsyncValidators: Array(0), …}
```

Which is great.

Next step was extending the `NgModelGroup` to attach the `formGroupName` to dynamically created groups and thereafter attaching the controls to their hosting groups

I followed the pattern, also aided by [this github issue contribution](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27716#issuecomment-448334557) and extended `NgModelGroup` to another directive - `DynamicGroupDirective`

```
export class DynamicGroupDirective extends NgModelGroup implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() config: GroupControlConfig;
  component: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(
    @Host() @SkipSelf() private parent: ControlContainer,
    @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALIDATORS) validators: any[],
    @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS) asyncValidators: any[],
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private container: ViewContainerRef
  ) {
    super(parent, validators, asyncValidators);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.name = this.config.name;
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<any>(component);
    component = this.container.createComponent(factory);
  }

  get path(): string[] {
    return [...this.config.breadcrumbs !, this.name];
  }
```

Now each control is assigned to its proper group host

Problem is, I cannot see any `DynamicGroupDirective` in the `this.parent.formDirective.directives` array, only `DynamicPanelDirective`s.

I noticed that the directives are being appended because of this appending:

```
// dynamic-panel.directive.ts ~ ngOnInit()
this._control = this.formDirective.addControl(this);
```

And I understand I have to utilize the matching function in the `DynamicGroupDirective`, which is

```
this.parent.formDirective.addFormGroup(this);
```

But I do not understand what do I need to assign in to, as it is not added to the directives array by itself, and I cannot assign to `this.control` as it is marked `readonly`

The usecase is to access the correct `DynamicGroupDirective` utilising the `config.breadcrumbs` which help with attaching it to the group, but I also need the dynamic component itself to be rendered inside its proper group `ViewContainerRef`

SO maybe someone has a better suggestion.. 
Thank you for anyone who has read up this far